Android logcat settings
Every time I press "Run" project on Android Studio - LogCat tab is opening. This is annoying.
Run->Edit Configurration->Miscellaneous->Show Logcat automatically does not work. My tool is "Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024" Can someone help me?

i just selected "Launch options" = "Nothing". Run->Edit Configurration->General->Launch options = "Nothing" or "Default Activity"
